# Adding a character before and after each text in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a long paragraph in Microsoft office(Word). The thing I want to do is, I want to add a fixed character (say "i") before and after each words in my doument. For example if there is a word in my paragraph, say "superuser" then it should become "isuperuseri", and this should happen to every other words in the paragraph. Though I know a character can be added after each word using find and replace method, but how about this one? Well, I'm using MS office's latest version.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Used find and replace ^w with that character, it adds before each word, but the problem is when there is a comma, like this superuser, it will not probably change like this superuseri, isn't it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open Find and Replace window.
- Find what: `(<*>)`
- Replace with: `i\1i`
- Click More, select `Use wildcards`
- Press Replace All

[image]

**Demo**

[image]

**Reading material:** [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)

Comment: Thanks, thats really cool and worked well, but whenever i try to format replace with as font color white, (because I don't want them to show the i)replacement works but everything disappeared, why so?

Comment: @Sayan Because the font color (replacement) is applied to the whole word. You need another find & replace that will apply the color.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get. What to find and what to replace with if you kindly elaborate. I want like this : isuperuseri, but these i's should be invisible due to white front color, and apparently it will appear as " superuser "

Comment: @Sayan The Replace with box applies the format to characters that were found. You will need to probably use VBA to find the i at the beginning and end of words, and change their font colors.

Comment: Please make your answer more "complete" - tell where to find info on the Wildcards and their syntax.

Comment: @Hannu See edit (link).